# Upper & Lower profile of a given shape

Tags: matlab, image-processing, connected-components

i would like to know if there is a method to extract the upper and lower profiles of a connected component.

One could first extract the contour and then split it to two sets of pixels, those in top and those in bottom, but i dont know how to decide a set of a given contour-pixel

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`bwboundaries`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html) - allowing you to trace the boundary of a binary mask in an image.
Once you traced the boundary of your object you can divide it into "upper" and "lower".